# OOP: How to force extending class to supply private method?

Tags: java, oop

**Example :** How would I make furtherSpecificProcessing method a private method?

**Reason:** I would like to be able to new an object of type B or C and only have doStuff() visible to programmer. while at the same time class B and C supply the additional functionality

```
abstract class A
{
  protected abstract void furtherSpecificProcessing();

  //concrete method utilizing abstract method
  public void doStuff()
  { 
   //busy code
   furtherSpecificProcessing();
   //more busy code
  }

public class B extends A
{
  public void furtherSpecificProcessing
  {
    //Class B specific processing
  }
}

public class C extends A
{
 public void furtherSpecificProcessing
 {
   //Class C specific processing
 }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not declaring it as protected ? (Or I'm missing something here ...)

Comment: Programming against interfaces.

Comment: Saw your edit. So why the method is declared as public in C and B ?

Comment: So as mentioned make the method `protected`. I don't see what else your asking at this point.

Comment: @user802421 I would have too much code redundancy. Both B and C essentially do the same thing except the they have there own furtherSpecificProcessing

Comment: How do you get redundancy? Put things that are common in super class (AbsA). While visibility cannot be restricted, you can hide them by exposing only interface to the user of the classes.

Comment: @user802421 Thanks I understand what your saying now and that would work also. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `furtherSpecificProcessing()` as protected, not as public in extending classes.

Comment: You could also make furtherSpecificProcessing as package private - which would be marginally less visible.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can force return type to be private for overriding method.

> Access     Must not be more restrictive. Can be less restrictive.

I would suggest reading [method overriding rules](http://code.google.com/p/learn-java/wiki/OverridenMethod).

Comment: Any design approach around this?

Comment: What do you mean by visible to programmer?

Comment: B b = new B();  b.doStuff();  or C c = new C() c.doStuff();  NOT b.doStuff() and b.furtherSpecificProcessing() or equally c.doStuff() and c.furtherSpecificProcessing()

Comment: As suggested by others you may try using protected and make sure related classes in same package.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the method as protected instead of public in both classes B and C.
Than what you need will work :

```
B b = new B();
b.doStuff(); // Will do stuff
b.furtherSpecificProcessing(); // Will not compile
```

and the same goes for instances of class C